# Not able to set cookie using django set_cookie

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am trying to set cookie using django set_cookie.
I am converting dict to string and then setting it in a cookie named 'blah'.
The cookie gets set, but I see that the commas are replaced with `\054`.

Python code

```
        x = {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
        }
        response.set_cookie('blah', json.dumps(x)) 
        return response
```

How I see it in chrome:

```
"{\"key1\": \"value1\"\054 \"key2\": \"value2\"\054 \"key3\": \"value3\"}"
```

Any pointer what am I missing - please suggest.

`django==4.2`

Comment: What do you mean with how to see it in crhome? This seems like the expected outcome, since `'\054' == ','`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any pointer what am I missing - please suggest.

**Nothing**. Indeed, this is exactly the same as a comma. Indeed, `'\054' == ','`:

```
> '\054' == ','
true
```

It is just how it *shows* a string, but the content is exactly the same. Indeed, if we thus would parse the JSON blob, we get:

```
> JSON.parse("{\"key1\": \"value1\"\054 \"key2\": \"value2\"\054 \"key3\": \"value3\"}");
{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }
```

So it parses it to the right JavaScript object. You can compare it to a string *literal* with `'foo'` and `"foo"`, both are presentations of the same value, just like `'\40'` and `' '` are the same as well.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. 

Yes, it works as expected - but I expect to see commas in the cookie value in chrome instead of 054.  

But I guess, I can live with it. :)

Comment: @Soumya: well me too, perhaps this is a setting how the developer console *logs* the content, but the format of logging a value is not the same as the value itself. You can present the same data in several ways.